# How can I connect to MySQL remotely and still keep it safe?

Tags: mysql, freebsd, remote-access

As you know, keeping the MySQL port 3306 open is unsafe. However, I would like to use a good MySQL administration program instead of phpMyAdmin, which requires 3306 port to be open.

Of course I can allow only my IP address to connect to port 3306 using ipfw. The problem is that my IP address changes every 24 hours, so I would have to add a new rule for every IP address.

Isn't there a better way to keep MySQL safe and still use the remote connection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, with SSH port forwarding.

On your local machine, issue the command

```
ssh -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 username@mysqlhost.com
```

and then you can connect your local MySQL admin tool to port 3306 on your local machine. You have to consider though that for the MySQL the connection appears to be coming from `127.0.0.1` as well, so the access rights for your MySQL user most be set accordingly.

If you happen to use a MySQL server on the local machine, port 3306 will be already taken, but you can just use a different port for the forwarding (`13306:127.0.0.1:3306`) and then point your admin tool to that different port.

(More info with `man ssh`).

---

**Edit** Some more explanations as an answer to your comments:

1. You will use this command on your local machine where you usually work, just before you want to do some administrative work on your database. What is does is to create a tunnel via SSH that forwards all traffic going to a port on your local machine to another port on another machine.
2. In this case, the tunnel ends on the MySQL server, which you contact directly via SSH. The part `username@mysqlhost.com` is just a placeholder, replace it with the username of your shell account and the IP address or host name of MysQL server. From your local machine, that will definitively not be `localhost` though. This part is not at all about your MySQL username, because SSH doesn't know about MySQL.
3. If you work as root on your database, you will connect your MySQL admin tool to port 3306 on the host `127.0.0.1` and use the username `root`. Although you work from a remote host, for the MysQL server the connection appears to coming from `localhost`, so the access permissions must be set accordingly.
4. SSH port forwarding / tunneling is an extremely powerful tool. You should definitely read more about it.

Comment: So, when I will use the command you gave, I'll be able to connect remotely to my mysql server, but then, local connection like website and other services wont be available until I forward the port? Sounds like a tunnel for me.

Comment: And what exactly does this mean: `username@mysqlhost.com` it should be `root@localhost` for a mysql `root` user?

Comment: @Cyclone: See my edit.

Comment: Look what I've added: http://pastebin.com/VHkyhTir
And I still can not connect remotely.

Comment: This unfortunately not work...

Comment: Have you managed to get the SSH connection working? If not, search on Serverfault or Google for the error message and you will get loads of hints what to do. And what *does not work* mean?

Comment: I'm trying to connect via Navicat to my mysql server, and it does not work.